# Alternative to cross apply (join on X in())

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, cross-apply

After lots of work, I made this (correct) query:

```
select count(distinct t1.code+t1.flname+t1.col1+t2.flname) 
from #t4 t1 cross apply (select flname from #t4 sq where sq.col1=t1.col1)t2
```

After lots of more work, I failed to produce an equivelant query without using cross apply. Is it possible? Maybe with WITH? How about not using WITH?

Comment: Your "correct" query may well not be correct. Concatenating 4 columns together might give you collisions.

Comment: Due to the nature of the fields as I know them, this is quite improbable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `join` should be equivalent:

```
select count(distinct t1.code + t1.flname + t1.col1 + sq.flname) 
from #t4 t1 join
     #t4 sq
     on sq.col1 = t1.col1;
```

Comment: What I want to do, verbally, is: for each record of #t4, give me a cross product with all the flnames who share a col1 with this record. So, the t1.col1=t2.col2 shall be used not on an inner join, but rather as a means to return a set of rows to make a cross join with.